# Why would Tom's Yeerk have to torture Cassie?

Tags: animorphs, yeerks

In [#53 The Answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Answer_(novel)), Tom's Yeerk brings what he thinks is a bludgeoned and beaten Cassie (not in morph) to Visser One. He then says:

> One of the Animorphs, Visser. My people captured her and questioned
>   her. Questioned her... forcefully.

Now, Tom's Yeerk is actually trying to trick Visser One. He hasn't actually done any questioning. However, presumably he would try to tell a believable story to the Visser.

So, why would Tom's Yeerk have to torture anyone? Why would the Yeerks have to question anyone to get information out of them? If they have a human they need information from, why not just stick a Yeerk in their head ASAP and get all the information? Why is Tom's Yeerk telling the Visser he tortured Cassie?

Obviously, if Cassie would have been in a morph too small to infest, it would have been another story. But here, she is in human form. (Actually, it's not even Cassie, but neither of the two Yeerks involved know that.)

Comment: Does Tom's Yeerk have access to subordinates, though? I recall him not being a high rank.

Comment: @Axelrod At this time he was the highest ranking officer of the Visser's security forces.

Comment: Smells like a plot hole, then, unless they were separated from a source of unhosted Yeerks.

Comment: @Axelrod Even if they were separated from a source of unhosted Yeerks, couldn't they just tie up some human controller and use that Yeerk? And possibly even kill the other human. (Doesn't seem out of character for those guys.)

Comment: [Torture for Fun  and Information?](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TortureForFunAndInformation)

Comment: @Adamant Yeah, the "fun" part seems like something Visser One and Tom's Yeerk would be into. A short while later the Visser talks about savouring the memory of people's death and capturing torture and murder on video for repeated replay at home. Classic villains :)